# Como mostrar um jPopupMenu logo abaixo de um jTextfield?

Tags: java, menu, popup, jtextfield

Minha intensão é criar um campo de busca onde se vá digitando e aparecendo os dados de uma consulta no BD como um popup menu. Isto já consegui, está funcionando. Criei o menu e consigo mostra-lo na tela com os dados, mas a posição é o problema: eu quero algo como o autocomplete da busca do Google! Do jeito que estou fazendo o menu fica por cima do TF e ainda ultrapassa em largura e ainda tem mais: nem sei se a forma como estou posicionando o menu é a mais adequada.

Meu código (a parte onde é criado o menu):

```
public void mostrarPopUp(DocumentEvent e) {
            tfTexto.setEditable(false);
            pumAutoComp.removeAll();
            List lista = buscar(tfTexto.getText());
            for (int i = 0; i< lista.size(); i++)
            {
                String nmItemMenu;
                nmItemMenu = lista.get(i).toString();
                System.out.println(nmItemMenu);
                JMenuItem item = new JMenuItem(nmItemMenu);
                pumAutoComp.add(item);
                tfTexto.add(pumAutoComp);
                tfTexto.setComponentPopupMenu(pumAutoComp);   
            }
             try {
                  int dotPosition = tfTexto.getCaretPosition();
                  Rectangle popupLocation = tfTexto.modelToView(dotPosition);
                  pumAutoComp.show(tfTexto, popupLocation.x, popupLocation.y);
            } catch (BadLocationException badLocationException) {
                  System.out.println("Oops");
            }
            tfTexto.setEditable(true);
        }
```

Imagem do meu menu atual:

[image: Menu atual]

Como eu gostaria: (nao se preocupem em fazer caber o texto, isso eu tbm ja consegui :))

[image: Menu ideal]

Comment: a parte "System.out.println(nmItemMenu);" Era só pra mim testar se estava buscando certinho! Podem ignorar!

Answer (score 1):

Sugiro em vez de pegar a posição do *caret* (que vai andando pra frente à medida que você digita o texto...) você pegar a posição ([`getLocation`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getLocation()) ou [`getLocationOnScreen`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getLocationOnScreen%28%29), não me lembro qual o correto) e as dimensões ([`getSize`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getSize())) do campo de texto, e especificar o tamanho do *popup* em relação a esses valores. Por exemplo:

```
int margem = 4; // Pro menu não ficar "agarrado" à caixa de texto

Point locTexto = tfTexto.getLocation(); // ou getLocationOnScreen
Dimension tamTexto = tfTexto.getSize();
pumAutoComp.setPopupSize(tamTexto.width, 300); // A altura é de sua escolha
pumAutoComp.show(tfTexto, locTexto.x, locTexto.y + tamTexto.height + margem);
```

Nota: o `setPopupSize` estabelece o tamanho preferencial, não necessariamente o tamanho real. Talvez seja necessário atribuir também os tamanhos mínimo e máximo para que o *popup* não cresça além da largura estabelecida.